# How to setup named instances using StructureMap profiles?

Tags: structuremap

I've done quite a bit of googling and searching here on SO, but couldn't find a similar question or answer.

In typical SM configuration you can add multiple named instances for a single PluginType:

```
ForRequestedType<IFoo>()
  .AddInstances( x => {
      x.OfConcreteType<FooA>().WithName( "FooA" );
      x.OfConcreteType<FooB>().WithName( "FooB" );
    } );
```

No problem there. The problem is that I can't do the same when creating a profile. Most examples explaining how to use profiles use the `For<>()` method of the passed `ProfileExpression`:

```
CreateProfile( "Default", p => {
    p.For<IFoo>().UseConcreteType<FooC>();
  } );
```

I can't seem to find a way to add multiple named instances for the same PluginType as you can do above with regular configuration. The only other method available through `ProfileExpression` is `Type<>()`, but I'm not sure if it can be used for this purpose.

**Edit:** I tried to use `Type<>()` instead of `For<>()` and it seems to be taking me in the right direction, but I bumped into another problem. To better explain it here's a better example of what I'm trying to do (this is what I posted to the structuremap-users group, no answer yet):

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize( x => {
    x.CreateProfile( "Nissan", p =>
    {
        p.Type<ICar>().Is.OfConcreteType<NewNissanCar>().WithName( "New" );
            p.Type<ICar>().Is.OfConcreteType<OldNissanCar>().WithName( "Old" );
    } );

    x.CreateProfile( "Honda", p =>
    {
        p.Type<ICar>().Is.OfConcreteType<NewHondaCar>().WithName( "New" );
        p.Type<ICar>().Is.OfConcreteType<OldHondaCar>().WithName( "Old" );
    } );

} );

ObjectFactory.Profile = "Nissan";

ICar newCar = ObjectFactory.GetNamedInstance<ICar>( "New" ); // -> returns NewHondaCar
ICar car = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICar>(); // -> returns OldNissanCar
```

So even though I set the profile to "Nissan", `GetNamedInstance<>("New")` returned an instance from the incorrect profile - it should've returned `NewNissanCar` instead of `NewHondaCar`.

Interestingly, `GetInstance<>()` uses the correct profile, but because I can't pass an instance name, it returns an arbitrary concrete type from that profile that implements `ICar` (I guess it just returns the last concrete type added for that interface).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on the syntax, but I believe this is correct:

```
container = new Container(x => {

    x.ForRequestedType<IFoo>()
        .AddInstances(y =>
        {
            y.OfConcreteType<FooA>().WithName("FooA");
            y.OfConcreteType<FooB>().WithName("FooB");
        });

    x.CreateProfile("Default")
        .For<IFoo>().UseNamedInstance("FooA");

});
```

Comment: That would work if I wanted to reuse an existing named instance. Unfortunately I'd like to register a new concrete type and give it a name. After looking at the example I gave in the question I think I should've not used FooA again in the profile. I'll try to fix it to clarify my intention.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like StructureMap respects named instances at the profile level. I just tried the car example with SM 2.6.3 and got the same results. You can also see it in the output of `ObjectFactory.WhatDoIHave()`:

```
ICar (ConsoleApplication1.ICar)                       
Scoped as:  Transient
      "New" Configured Instance of ConsoleApplication1.NewHondaCar, ConsoleApplication1
      "Old" Configured Instance of ConsoleApplication1.OldHondaCar, ConsoleApplication1
```

It looks like the profiles might be implemented internally by using the name as well, which would explain why it's not supported. When I registered a non-named instance for each profile, I see this in the output:

```
ICar (ConsoleApplication1.ICar)                       
Scoped as:  Transient
      "Default Instance for Profile Nissan" Configured Instance of ConsoleApplication1.NewNissanCar, ConsoleApplication1
      "Default Instance for Profile Honda" Configured Instance of ConsoleApplication1.NewHondaCar, ConsoleApplication1
```

Notice how the name of the profile is actually part of the instance key's name. I haven't walked through the code, but this is what appears to be happening.